# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do a "many to many" jpa mapping.

I have a table called "Account":

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        })
@JoinTable(name = "account_user",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

I have table called "User":

```
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        mappedBy = "user")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<>();
```

I get the following error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.bank.account.model.Account.user in com.bank.account.model.User.accounts

A join "many to many" table called "AccountUser" is supposed to be created by the mapping.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

Answer (score 1):

MappedBy must refer to the attribute name in the target class. In your case it's users not user.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        mappedBy = "users")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<>();
```